# SAML on Domino 9.0.1 sending blank Issuer with AuthnRequest

Tags: ibm-domino, saml

Trying SAML with SSOCircle as IdP provider.

Imported the public Idp metadata from SSOCircle into IdP Config document in idpconfig.nsf. Exported idp.xml from Domino and imported into SSOCircle.

Since out-of-box supported IdP's are ADFS and TFIM, set a new option called Other in IdP provider Product field.
When I try to reach Domino host, SAMLRequest token and RelayState are successfully generated and included as query params and successfully redirected to Idp SSO URL. However, there it is erroring out.

Upon inspection using SAML tracer, the AuthnRequest is missing values for Issuer and AssertionConsumerServiceURL. Why???

Comment: Sample AuthRequest generated by Domino

Comment: <samlp:AuthnRequest 
                    ID="_bec424fa5103428909a30ff1e31168327f79474984"
                    Version="2.0"
                    IssueInstant="2011-10-01T11:39:34Z"
                    ForceAuthn="false"
                    IsPassive="false"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL=""
                    >
    <saml:Issuer/>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
                        Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/></samlp:AuthnRequest>

Comment: Exactly the same problem here and some other stuff missing too like Signature URL parameter.